# When do we use media-queries "resolution" in css?

Tags: css, media-queries, resolution

Today, i discovered [`The resolution CSS data types`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution) and i don't find a real usage for this. Has anyone ever used this functionality or any examples use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One real-world example usage is when performing printing of web document:

```
@media print and (min-resolution: 300dpi) { ... }
```

The above media query will display given styles when printing DPI is set at minimum of 300dpi.

Comment: Thank. I never thought at this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some content that requires at least 300dpi (artist / photographer etc.) you could require the viewer to have at least a 300dpi screen. If the viewer does not, you can put out a message saying they don't have a screen with high enough pixel density to view the content.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you’re displaying images, via CSS, in a same-sized element:

```
.my-image {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.jpg);

  /* Exact dimensions of image */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

This will look fabulous until you see this on a higher DPI screen. Incidentally, many smartphones and tablets do have higher DPI screens. With a media query, you can serve higher quality images.

```
@media (min-resolution: 72dpi) {
  .my-image {
    background-image: url(path/to/image-large.jpg);
  }
}
```

Basically progressive enhancement. Users with lower DPI screens will run at you, hold you in their arms, and thank you for saving precious bandwidth.